# my smart contract always return empty when testing with rinkerby network

Tags: solidity, remix, rinkeby

I am trying to implement the simple storage.

When calling `set` function, the contract will append a new `Log` object to `logs` array, and also return the related `index` to the caller for reference data.

The problem is I cannot get returned `index`, it is always empty.

How can I get the `index` from calling `set` function?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Storage {
    struct Log {
        string fname;
        string lname;
        string dob;
    }
    mapping (uint => Log) logs;

    uint index = 0;

    function set(string memory fname, string memory lname, string memory dob) public returns (uint) {
        index++;
        logs[index] = Log(fname, lname, dob);
        return (index);
    }

    function get(uint idx) public view returns (string memory, string memory, string memory) {
        return (logs[idx].fname, logs[idx].lname, logs[idx].dob);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Remix, you need to click on the **[vm]from:0xca3...** line in the console at the bottom after you've called the function. There will be a row in the table labeled **decoded output** which will give you the return value.

Comment: `decoded output` always empty, it is incorrect value